# Override or Stop Window Resize Event writing a new jQuery function

Tags: jquery, resize

How can I Override/Stop that Window Resize Event writing a new function without deleting this existing one?

Any kind of Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function ($) {

    $.fn.customQuickSearch = function () {

        var onResize = function () {

            var containerWidth = $quickSearch.width();
            if (containerWidth > 225) {
                $quickSearch.removeClass('quicksearchbar_Narrow');
                $quickSearch.addClass('quicksearchbar_Wide');
            } else {
                $quickSearch.removeClass('quicksearchbar_Wide');
                $quickSearch.addClass('quicksearchbar_Narrow');
            }

        }

        $(window).resize(onResize);

        $(window).trigger('resize');

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, would you be able clarify

Comment: OK. I just want to stop/override this function without editing this one. I mean writing a new function.

Comment: That's still not clear, if you want to remove the bound event `$(window).off('resize');` if you want to bind another resize event `$(window).resize(yourFunction);`.

Comment: For not resizing window anymore. Clear?

Comment: That still isn't clear, could you please try to describe the outcome you want instead of the problem? Do you want to remove the current window resize event binding? Do you want to bind _another_ resize event to the `window`?

Comment: Please this link http://www.lascrucesdigs.com/

Comment: How does that help? All I can see is an obvious `not defined` error because you're using wordpress which uses [jQuery in no conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). Just wrap your jQuery from custom-script.js in `(function($){ /* your code */  }(jQuery));` or use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: I just want to not to resize event happened or trigger it on the very begining of the page load for quick search bar at the top.

Comment: Hi Joe,
No Luck yet!
One Last request... can you please check my custom-script.js and let me know if need any correction?
Many Thanks!!!

Comment: You're going to have to do that yourself or hire someone to do it for you. Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions not a place to get people to do your work for you.

Comment: OK, I understand. No worries! I'll do it somehow. Thanks for your kind cooperation !

Comment: No problem, hope you get it fixed!